# display a plain list of intrinsic data types

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

It's paradox: I can display a list/collection/set/whatever of complex objects in a datagrid/listview so that the user can edit these complex objects.

**But**: I can not do this with a plain old list of int/string/double.

This is what I have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<int> angles = new ObservableCollection<int>{60, 180, 240, 300, 360};
}
```

I want the user to be able to edit existing values, to add new values and to remove values.

Which Control is the best for this purpose? (I tried DataGrid, but didn't get any result.)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You or i seem to have a misunderstanding here. DataGrid - as the name suggests -- displays objects in multiple columns per row - each column representing a certain property of that object. If you have a list of *int*, why would you want to use a DataGrid (it would just have a single column) instead of a ListBox?

Comment: I am not stuck to a DataGrid. I can use whatever Control might fit.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a collection of a new class that has one int, rather than binding to a list of ints:

```
public class Foo  //TODO give meaningful name
{
    public Int Value {get;set;} //TODO give meaningful name
}
```

This way the data grid can get the value, set the value, add new `Foo` objects with a value, delete a `Foo` object with it's value, etc.

The `int` itself, being immutable, cannot be modified.  You could display a list of values doing what you have done in your question, and add/remove values, but not edit them.

Comment: This is what I found out by myself... But I certainly do not want to wrap a `int` and don't add any functionality. There must be another way, to display a list of `int`s and let the user edit, add and remove items!

Comment: @Rico-E Why don't you want to wrap an `int`?  It *is* adding functionality.  It is creating a *mutable* wrapper for an *immutable* object.  The fact that the type is mutable, rather than immutable, is *very important* here, as it is functionality that you need to have.   There certainly are other ways of displaying a list of ints for a user to edit, add, and remove, but this is almost certainly the easiest and most effective.

Comment: I am not sure if it would work, but you could let code do the boixing for you. Try this:
ObservableCollection<object> angles = new ObservableCollection<int>{60, 180, 240, 300, 360};
I didn't try it myself. Just an idea so you don't have to write and use a wrapper.

Comment: @Rhyous That wouldn't help the situation at all.  Casting an `int` to `object` doesn't suddenly make it mutable.

Comment: Your probably right. I was just wondering if using Boxing would cause the int to be boxed into an instance of Object and I thought Object was mutable but perhaps it is not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: @Rhyous Casting an immutable object to `object` doesn't make it mutable.  If you could mutate the object, even by casting it, then *it wouldn't be immutable any more*.

Comment: Servy, You are missing the point of what I was trying to do. I am NOT trying to make a string mutable. I get that unless you use "unsafe" a string is immutable. I was looking to avoid writing a wrapper by searching for an already existing way to wrap it.

Comment: @Rhyous There certainly *are* existing types that you could use to do this, but those mechanisms are largely intended for other purposes than creating a mutable wrapper for an immutable object.  It results in unclear code because the semantic intentions of the mechanisms you're using don't match your actual goals.  Creating a new type like this results in much clearer code that semantically means what you want it to mean.  And that clearer code comes at the cost of just a few dozen characters of code.  More than worth it.  if writing this class took more than a few seconds...

Comment: Agreed. It was fun to try, but I came to a similar conclusion.

Comment: @Rhyous For the record, the simplest existing method of creating a mutable wrapper would be a collection of size one.  Put the type into an array of size one, rather than trying to deal with boxing it (the automatic boxing/unboxing makes using boxing for these purposes *very* hard).  However, as I explained in my last comment, that still isn't nearly as beneficial as a new custom type.